# Is there a space in which the $\vec a$ in $\sin(a_1\cdot x)+\sin(a_2\cdot x)$ is linear?

Tags: trigonometry, transformation

I have equations of the form $\sin(a_1\cdot x)+\sin(a_2\cdot x)=y$ (actually more complicated, but that's the general essence). I want to solve for $\vec a$ using linear regression instead of non-linear regression / optimization / etc. Is there perhaps some transform that would give me something like $$T[\sin(a_1\cdot x)+\sin(a_2\cdot x)] = a_1\cdot x + a_2\cdot x = T[y]$$ that I could then use linear regression to solve? I know of existing methods like the Lomb-Scargle Periodogram etc but I am trying to understand whether there is a separate route.

Comment: Why is $x=sin^{-1}(y)$ worse that $x = ln(y)$?

Comment: Oh, good point. Ok, I actually have $\sin(a)+\sin(b)=y$, so I don't think I can do $\sin^-1$ since it's not a linear operator.

Comment: @Yves sorry if it's unclear, the $x_1$ and $x_2$ are the unknowns, and I have many known $y$s. Does that make more sense now?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I've tried to edit the question to make it more clear for you

Comment: Not at all. There are no $x_1, x_2$ it seems. See my answer.